# How do I check version of alpine mail client?

Tags: unix, version, alpine-linux

How do I check on a Unix server what version of the Alpine mail client is installed?

I have root access in case that is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh, just found it:

```
alpine -version
```

Comment: thanks to http://macosx.com/forums/unix-x11/20330-how-do-i-check-versions-unix.html

Comment: On Alpine v3.10.2 I was NOT able to use `alpine -version` I tried `ash` ans `zsh` as shell

Comment: you have to run apk add alpine, before you can execute that.

Answer (score 78):

That works even without `alpine` installed (e.g. in Docker container):

```
$ cat /etc/alpine-release 
3.4.6
```

Comment: While this does answer _my_ question (and probably _yours_), this is how to check the _Alpine OS_ version, not the Text-based email client. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to run the command `alpine -v` or `alpine -version` ... you can also start Alpine and press `?` on the main menu to open the main Help page, which will also tell you the version.

If your system has a package manager that you used to install Alpine, you can also check with that.  For example, on my Debian system, I'd run:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep alpine
ii  alpine      1.10+dfsg-3     Text-based email client, friendly for novices but powerful
```